# What could be causing: "Uncaught TypeError: this.captcha_ip.form.submit is not a function" in this (downloaded) javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm a total noob to javascript and also this is my first time doing anything but reading this website so maybe I have gone about this all wrong. I've been using PHP+HTML as a hobby for almost 20 years for basic, static websites, but for an M.Arch university project I decided to build a website for a zine, which includes a contact form where I'd like people to be able to submit articles and attachments.

I downloaded an example form and reskinned it to fit the site, but for some reason, the javascript - which I haven't altered in any way - doesn't seem to work. The source website ( https://html.form.guide/contact-form/contact-form-attachment/ ) doesn't seem to have a contact form for me to ask them what's what, and a bit of googling and looking through other stack overflow questions isn't helping, possibly because I don't know enough about javascript to even have the right keywords.

When I inspect the form in my browser, clicking the submit button brings up this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.captcha_ip.form.submit is not a function
    at FG_CaptchaValidator.OnSuccess (fg_captcha_validator.js:42)
    at _OnSuccess (fg_captcha_validator.js:120)
    at XMLHttpRequest._StateHandler (fg_captcha_validator.js:143)
```

Here's the function in the downloaded javascript (I really have absolutely no clue where to even begin to bugtest something like this) that the line is part of:

```
 function FG_CaptchaValidator(captcha_ip,captcha_img)
{
    this.captcha_ip = captcha_ip;
    
    this.captcha_img = captcha_img;

    this.validatedCode=''  

    this.validate = function()
    {
        if(this.validatedCode.length==0 ||
           this.validatedCode != this.captcha_ip.value)
        {
            this.ValidateOnline();
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

  this.OnSuccess = function()
  {
     var msg = this.GetResponseText();
     if(msg == 'success')
     {
        this.validatedCode = this.captcha_ip.value;
        if(this.captcha_ip.form.onsubmit())
        {
            this.captcha_ip.form.submit();
        }
     }
     else
     {
        sfm_show_error_msg(msg,this.captcha_ip);
        document.error_disp_handler.FinalShowMsg();
     }
     
  }

  this.ValidateOnline = function()
  {
      var url = captcha_img.src;
      var postStr = this.captcha_ip.name + "=" + 
      encodeURIComponent( this.captcha_ip.value )+'&fg_validate_captcha=y';

      this.Init('POST', url);

      this.Send(postStr);
  }
}
```

I hope there's something obvious that's just slightly off in this code, because I really don't know where to start with javascript. I know it's a bit like PHP, lots of similar functionality, just at different ends... but the actual syntax..?

If it's not this code, then perhaps I've messed something up in my reskin of the contact form itself, or the way the scripts are included, or, I don't know.. Any guidance would be appreciated!

EDIT TO BRING STUFF IN FROM COMMENTS/ELABORATE: Within my `<head>` section for every page I bring in metajava.php: `<?php require("metajava.php"); ?>` within that file I have the scripts included (amongst others): `<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/gen_validatorv31.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/fg_captcha_validator.js"></script>`
I think these two scripts must be getting included correctly, or the browser's inspection console (I use Brave) wouldn't be pointing me to the proper line of the script in the error, and the scripts wouldn't show up in the sources tab(?)

I don't get any 404 errors; the form simply does not submit or appear to do anything *unless* I'm inspecting the page and see the console error. If I click submit once (with the inspect console open) I get the error I quoted at the beginning, and if I *slam it repeatedly like the migrainous bean I am* lately, I get a 500 error.
I've also done a little test of the PHP includes by way of adding
`echo "filename-for-each-required-include.php included";` to each php include with the title of the file, and they all come in at the top correctly, though it breaks the captcha so I've removed it again now that I know they're working.

I still wonder if it's a javascript syntax thing that I'm not picking up bc I don't know anything really about javascript. I have modified a few simple scripts before but it was VERY trial and error and this is such a complicated looking expression I don't know where to start - is it even *meant* to be a function?

PS: Thanks for literally YEARS of solving my problems without my even needing to sign up and ask <3

Comment: I have never used php lol but lets see if I can help. The error you are getting is because Javascript is saying this is not a function or at least I don't know it to be. The first step is to make sure you are including the JS. Do you see any 404 errors?

Comment: The form shows `src='scripts/gen_validatorv31.js'></script>` but lets make sure that it's getting included.

Comment: I downloaded the contact form and captcha doesn't really work but the forms show.

Comment: Within my <head> section for every page I bring in metajava.php:
`<?php require("metajava.php"); ?>`
within that file I have the scripts included (amongst others):
`<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/gen_validatorv31.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/fg_captcha_validator.js"></script>`
I figured it must be getting included, or it wouldn't be pointing me to the proper line of the script in the error ?

No 404 errors - if I click submit once (with the inspect console open) I get the error I quoted above, if I slam it repeatedly I get a 500 error.

Comment: Please share, ill review